# MacBook Pro Retina 13" not connecting to some Wifi networks

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

I just bought a MacBook Pro Retina 13" with Mavericks and all the latest updates, and have an issue connecting to some Wifi networks that my Windows Laptop and my Windows Phone had no issue with at all.

I have sucessfully connected to my own Wifi router (Asus) and various coffee shop wifi access points.

However it does not connect to the Wifi in my local coffee shop at all. It just shows 'Connection time out' after about 5 seconds.

It is not the WPA2 password, because I can connect to it from my wifi enabled phone (Nokia Lumia 920) with no issue. (I deleted the Wifi connection on my phone and reconnected to make sure)

Are there any steps I can take to get my MacBook working with all the routers again?

Comment: not sure if this would help but I have had times when my mac (and sometimes iphone) would not connect to wifi when other windows machines around me have no issues. we traced it down to the fact that some wifi's that do not support apples but if you can't check what device/setting is on the public wifi I guess you wouldn't be able to fix it.

Comment: Yes, I have seen some internet forums discussing issues with Apples and specific types of routers. It seems a bit crazy if it is the router's responsibility to support the Apple, not the other way around. You are also right to say that diagnoses on the router is not feasible for public wifi.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the 'Connection time out' happens on weak WiFi signal.

I am assuming you have a decent signal, and further assuming there is something wrong with the saved WiFi profile for that specific location.

To test that:

Follow this guide to connect using copy paste.

In Terminal type following (to turn the airport on)

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

Next type (to scan for networks and find the one you want)

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport scan
```

From the Scan above you will get a display of available networks, so pick the one you want and type following (to connect).....while at it look at the RSSI number, the lower the better like (-) 50 or lower.   <sub>The RSSI is the signal to Noise ration, and if it is a high number (70 or higher) there is your problem.</sub>

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 WIFI_SSID_I_WANT_TO_JOIN WIFI_PASSWORD
```

skip the password if none.

If above worked, then lets open your WiFi find and Delete that profile, then make a new one.